# Calculate number of sales days in DAX

Tags: dax, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

1/ How to calculate the **number of sales days** (= number of days at least one sale has been done)?

So far, I created this measure, but I'd like to know if another more optimal solution exists for a large sales table (1b+ records):

```
Sales[No of Sales Days] :=
        CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( Sales[Date Key] )
        )
```

2/ How to calculate **number of sales days in the current year**? Is anything more optimal than this?

```
Sales[No of Sales Days YTD] :=
    CALCULATE ( 
        [No of Sales Days], 
        DATESYTD ( 'Calendar'[Calendar Date] )
    )
```

Comment: Do you have a date dimension?

Comment: @David, yes, I have a calendar dimension.

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is a better code as DISTINCTCOUNT is a problematic structure in DAX. Please try this, and confirm the results back to me!

Q1)

```
Sales[No of Sales Days] :=
CALCULATE ( SUMX ( VALUES ( Sales[Date Key] ), 1 ) )
```

Q2)

```
Sales[No of Sales Days YTD] :=
VAR CurrentYear =
    YEAR ( TODAY () )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [No of Sales Days],
        FILTER ( ALL ( Calendar[Year] ), Calendar[Year] = CurrentYear )
    )
```

Comment: Interesting, SUMX(..., 1), thanks. Although, VALUES is considering current filter context, which might be different than current year.

Comment: Yes, You are right. VALUES always takes current visible filter context into account. If you want a specific year(current year etc..) you can use a year slicer, and pick the year you want. Or inside measure, define a filter. Like this: Table[Year] = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Year])

Comment: I think ALL should be used instead of VALUES. But remains question 2...

Comment: Also code provided by @David below is really fast as he used golden function 'summarize'.

Comment: If you use all as table function, the result will be the same, I think. In terms of performance-wise, there won't be much difference; but you need to test and see it yourself.

Comment: did you see the second question in my post?

Comment: Now, I saw. I think You can solve it as I gave you the hint above. If you can't, I will be glad to recommend a solution. 

Comment: I added a solution for question 2.

Comment: Good Solution- Time Intelligence! It adds the cumulative total. I also added as an alternative in my post.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your model. There are a few options which have been written about.

https://gorilla.bi/dax/optimize-distinctcount/
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/analyzing-distinctcount-performance-in-dax/

I would try a few different options e.g.:

```
Sales[No of Sales Days] =
   COUNTROWS(
      SUMMARIZE(
          ‘Sales’
          ,’Sales[Date Key]
          )
      )
```